# JQuery Chosen: Not Updating Select Option In Background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am using the JQuery Chosen Plugin to fancy up my select options. The Plugin itself is working fine. However some of my dropdowns use AJAX POST to filter / pull back a refined list of options in another Select.

The JQuery Plugin, is added and not changed. But for some reason when I select an option in a Select that filters a secondary select, the secondary select doesnt seem to recognise that an option has been selected.

Any ideas? Has anyone come across this issue before?

```
            <div class="search-line">
                <div class="search-option">
                    <label>Asset Type:</label>
                    <select name="AssetType" id="AssetType">
                        <?php

                        $type_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT AssetType.AssetTypeTitle AS HardwareAssetAssetTypeTitle, HardwareAssetAssetTypeID FROM HardwareAsset INNER JOIN AssetType ON (AssetType.AssetTypeID = HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetTypeID) ORDER BY HardwareAssetAssetTypeTitle ASC";

                        $type = sqlsrv_query($database_connection, $type_sql);

                        if (!sqlsrv_has_rows($type)){
                            echo "<option>No Records Found</option>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<option value= ''>Select Asset Type</option>";
                            while($type_option = sqlsrv_fetch_object($type)){
                                echo "<option value='$type_option->HardwareAssetAssetTypeID'>".$type_option->HardwareAssetAssetTypeTitle."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="search-option">
                    <label>Asset Sub-Type:</label>  
                    <select name="AssetSubType" id="AssetSubType">
                        <option value="">Select Asset Type First</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

AJAX:

```
$('#AssetType').on('change',function(){
    var AssetAssetTypeID = $(this).val();
    if(AssetAssetTypeID != 0){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/ITSMIS/data/asset/search.php',
            data:'AssetAssetTypeID='+AssetAssetTypeID,
            success:function(data){
                $('#AssetSubType').html(data);
            }
        }); 
    }
    else{
        $('#AssetSubType').html('<option value="">Select Asset Type First</option>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the onchange function you wrote for the first select?

Comment: updated with the onchange, hope that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this before, not sure why but doing the onchange like below works for me:

```
$('body').on('change','#AssetType',function(){
    var AssetAssetTypeID = $(this).val();
    if(AssetAssetTypeID != 0){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/ITSMIS/data/asset/search.php',
            data:'AssetAssetTypeID='+AssetAssetTypeID,
            success:function(data){
                $('#AssetSubType').html(data);
            }
        }); 
    }
    else{
        $('#AssetSubType').html('<option value="">Select Asset Type First</option>');
    }
});
```

Comment: nothing, i have added alerts into the code to see if it runs through it, which it does, strangely enough, if i do a search on the form, the option selected in the dropdown is recognised as the value.